# String searching not working with requests result

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to extract some data from html dumped into a string, but for some reason my `re.search()` function doesn't seem to be working.

```
import requests
import re

gamertag = 'AI52487963'
   
max_url = 'https://halo.bungie.net/stats/playerstatshalo2.aspx?player={}'.format(gamertag)
max_data = requests.get(max_url)
max_data_text = max_data.text
  
result = re.search('\"PageCount\":(.*),\"EditMode\":', max_data_text) 
max_pages = result.group(1)
```

This should give me the answer of 131 from the page, but I get a `NoneType object of builtins module` error instead. If I replace the `max_data.text` with the copy pasted text data from the source of the page, but `re.search()` works just fine and gives me the right answer of 131, but it's not programmatic:

```
max_data_text = """ mainContent_bnetpgl_recentgames_ctl00\",\"UniqueID\":\"ctl00$mainContent$bnetpgl$recentgames$ctl00\",\"PageSize\":25,\"PageCount\":131,\"EditMode\":\"EditForms\""""
result = re.search('\"PageCount\":(.*),\"EditMode\":', max_data_text) 
max_pages = result.group(1)
```

Am I missing something with how `re.search()` handles certain types of string data? Are python strings that are instantiated via `x = """ test """` different than a string that's made via `string_foo.text`?

Comment: No, a string is a string is a string.  What you're getting from `max_data.text` has to be different than the string literal you're replacing it with if the `re.search` call returns a different result in each case. - have you printed out the value in `max_data.text` to make sure it is what you think it is?  How about copy/pasting the result of that print back into your code as a literal.  That should produce the same result, although special characters can at times get lost in a copy/paste, so that won't be 100% true in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to espace each backslash of the input string with a backslash :

```
result = re.search('\\\\"PageCount\\\\":(.*),\\\\"EditMode\\\\":', max_data_text)
print(result.group(1)) # '131'
```

Because your input string (in your first snippet) is like `\\"PageSize\\":25,\\"PageCount\\":131,\\"EditMode\\":\\"EditForms\\",\\"CurrentPageIndex\\":0` (unlike your second snippet where the quotes are only escaped with a single backslash)

As pointed out in comment by @Steve, it can be made cleaner by using a raw string:

```
result = re.search(r'\\"PageCount\\":(.*),\\"EditMode\\":', max_data_text)
```

Comment: Note: A raw string makes for a cleaner expression: `result = re.search(r'\\"PageCount\\":(.*),\\"EditMode\\":', max_data_text)`